# Submit form using ajax: Was working, now not working?

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following HTML form in signup.php:

```
<form id="signup" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false">
     <div class="signup_row action">
     <input type="text" placeholder="What's your Name?" name="name" id="name" class="signup" autocomplete="new-password" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" required />
     <input type="text" placeholder="Got an Email?" name="email" id="email" class="signup" autocomplete="new-password" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" required />
     <div class="g-recaptcha" style="margin-top:30px;" data-sitekey="6LeCkZkUAAAAAOeokX86JWQxuS6E7jWHEC61tS9T"></div>
     <input type="submit" class="signup_bt" name="submit" id="submt" value="Create My Account">
     </div> 
 </form>
```

I am trying to submit the form using ajax, without page refresh:

```
<!-- include files -->
<?php include 'assets/config.php';?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["CUSTOMER_ID"])){
header('Location: myaccount.php'); } ?>  


    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {      

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'do_signup_check.php',
            data:{"name":name,"email":email},
            success: function () {
            if(result == 0){    
                $('.signup_side').fadeOut(500).promise().done(function() {
                $('.signup_side').load('do_signup.php',function(){}).hide().fadeIn(500);
            });
            }else{
                $('.signup_side').fadeOut(500).promise().done(function() {
                $('.signup_side').load('assets/login.php',function(){}).hide().fadeIn(500);
            }         
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

I am posting the form to do_signup_check.php and running a query to see if the user is already registered. echo 1 for a positive result and 0 for a negative result:

Do_Signup_Check.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();        
    require 'assets/connect.php';


    $myName=$_POST["name"];
    $myEmail=$_POST["email"];

    $check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_verification WHERE email='".$myEmail."'");

    if (!$check) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0){
        echo '1';
    }else{  
        echo '0';
    }

?>
```

If the result is 0 then the ajax should load my page do_signup.php.
But alas it is not getting this far. It was working and then i switched off the computer and came back to it and now it won't work.

Please can someone show me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: So what did you change?

Comment: Are there errors in your browser's console? One thing you are doing wrong is directly inserting values into SQL statements, use prepared statements.

Comment: You're not assigning values to the `name` and `email` variables in your javascript.

Comment: Change `data:{"name":name,"email":email},` to `data:{name:name, email:email},`

Comment: Also, the whole of your first PHP script is dependent on the session variable CUSTOMER_ID; return something if that is not present to check this.

Comment: Add an error handler.... What is `result` ?

Comment: where u defined these 2  `data:{"name":name,"email":email}`

Answer (score 1):

`if(result == 0){` here result is not using in success function:

you must need to pass resultant variable here:

```
success: function () {
```

as:

```
success: function (result) {
```

Now, you can use your condition `if(result == 0){`

**Second,** i suggest you to pass `dataType: 'html'` in your ajax request.

**Edit:**

You are using `<?php if(isset($_SESSION["CUSTOMER_ID"])){` line in your code, if you are not using `session_start()` in your code then this check will not work.

For this line `data:{"name":name,"email":email},` i didnt see `name` and `email` in your code, where you define these 2 variables which you are using in your ajax params.